# Getting result of call is unused while defining protocol with initializer

Tags: swift

I have a protocol:

```
protocol ApiEndpointsProtocol {
    func getKey(for endpoint: API.Keys, withChar: Bool) -> String
}
```

and I want to initialize `withChar` to be always true if no value is provided, this is my attempt:

```
extension ApiEndpointsProtocol {
    func getKey(for endpoint: API.Keys, withChar: Bool = true) {
        getKey(for: endpoint, withChar: withChar)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting a warning on the function call: `getKey(for: endpoint, withChar: withChar)`

```
Result of call to 'getKey(for:withChar:)' is unused
```

What's the right approach to do this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoever marked that question as duplicate, that one is using a completion handler and has no mention of what I'm talking about of the function not being used, please be mindful.

Comment: The required function in the protocol has a `-> String` return value, but as the warning states it's unused.

Comment: I understand what it says, how can I fix it? I'm using it when I call the protocol itself, but what does it has to do with defining it? @vadian

Comment: You have to add `-> String` also in the extension. But the function is pointless as you can specify a default value anyway.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it. I didn't try that again because I had try it at the beginning and didn't work. Thank you @vadian